Question deleted
The question "Ratio between Expected Shortfall and Value at Risk for t-distribution" by user @michaelaba was deleted shortly after I wrote what I thought was a pretty nice answer.
How come? Was it a case of a "hit-and-run", ask-question-get-answer-then-delete? If so, is there a way to prevent this?

I've undeleted the question, not sure why it was deleted but this questiona and answer should not be destroyed.
